# Running Disco in a Docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, disco

I need to run a run a Python script in a Docker container (I currently have execution of "disco_test.py" as my `ENTRYPOINT` command) that will utilize Disco (which of course needs to be running in that container). The problem is I cannot seem to get Disco running either with `CMD` or `RUN` in the Dockerfile, or from within the Python script itself (using the subprocess module).

If, however, I create an otherwise identical image with no `ENTRYPOINT` command, run it with `docker run -i -t disco_test /bin/bash` and then open a Python shell, I can successfully get Disco running using the subprocess module (simply using `call(["disco", "start"])` works). Upon exiting the Python shell I can indeed verify that Disco is still running properly (`disco status` reports "Master 0cfddb8fb0e4:8989 running"). When I attempt to start Disco in the same way (using `call(["disco", "start"])`) from within "disco_test.py", which I execute as the `ENTRYPOINT` command, it doesn't work! It will print "Master 0cfddb8fb0e4:8989 started", however checking `disco status` afterwards ALWAYS shows "Master 0cfddb8fb0e4:8989 stopped".

Is there something about how the `ENTRYPOINT` command is run that is preventing me from being able to get Disco running from within the corresponding Python script? Running "disco_test.py" on my machine (not in a Docker container) does indeed get Disco up and running successfully.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that its running daemonized and exits immediately stopping the container. You could try these containers [dockerized disco](https://github.com/gijzelaerr/discodocker) . It uses supervisor to run disco.